# Video tag won't autoplay in firefox, DOMException

Tags: javascript, firefox, video, stream, webrtc

I'm using Firefox 62.0.3 on my tablet, it works on one of the tablets but not the other.
On one tablet I am getting an error that says
`DOMException: "The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request."`
I am not at all sure what this is telling me, does my video need to be within a clickhandler? I thought if autoplay is true and muted is true, i am good to go?
Again it works on the other tablet with the same firefox version.

`<video id="asd" class="asd" oncreate={(el) => stream.start(el)}> Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.</video>`

I then do

```
this.peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
        const mediaStream = event.streams[0];
        let remoteVideoElement = document.getElementById('stream');
        remoteVideoElement.autoplay = "true";
        remoteVideoElement.defaultMuted = "true";
        remoteVideoElement.muted = "muted";
        remoteVideoElement.playsinline = "true";

        if ('srcObject' in remoteVideoElement) {
            remoteVideoElement.srcObject = mediaStream;
        } else {
            // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
            remoteVideoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
        }
        let playPromise = remoteVideoElement.play();

        if (playPromise !== undefined) {
            playPromise.then((_) => {
                // will play video
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error("playPromise error: ", err);
            })
        } else {
            console.error("playPromise is undefined: ", playPromise);
            remoteVideoElement.load();
        }
    }
```

It works but when i try to resolve `playPromise` it gives the DOMException error, and `load()` does not work either on the tablet that is giving issues.

Comment: Do you have any fiddle link for it?

Comment: Firefox just recently started preventing media autoplay without user interaction

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui i do not. This isn't something that you can reproduce as it relates to streaming from hardware that I have.

Comment: @charlietfl yeah they did, though I am on version `62.0.3` on both tablets and on one it works perfectly fine. Both are on Android version `8.1.0`, Samsung Experience version `9.5`. is there something in `about:config` that i am missing?

Comment: What do you mean "when I try to resolve `playPromise`? Does the text `playPromise error: ` appear directly in front of the error message? I'm puzzled why it says `DOMException: ` and not `AbortError: `.

Comment: @jib hey, yeah i'm not so sure as well. this appears in the console. i believe you are actually the one helping me on Bugzilla. For people who want more info as well, `https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1566584`